# Getting Schemas from Oracle DB throwing error

Tags: sql, oracle, select, data-dictionary

This query

```
select distinct owner from dba_objects
```

is throwing this error

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Does that make any sense at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an administrative user (such as `sys` or `system`). If you do not have access to such a user, you could use the `all_objects` view instead of `dba_obejcts`. Any user can query it, and will get results only for the objects it has privileges to.

Answer (score 1):

It does if you don't have select privs on the DBA_OBJECTS view or if you don't have a local or global synonym to the SYS.DBA_OBJECTS view.  You could try selecting from SYS.DBA_OBJECTS instead.

Answer (score 1):

As others state, this is a privileges issue.

However, if a user needs access to the more privileged DBA data dictionary objects you should grant them the SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE role. Connecting with SYS or SYSTEM, or even as a DBA, should be discouraged for normal operations.